# Degree of face of icosahedron is $3$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a polyhedral graph with $12$ vertices and $30$ edges I know that it is The Icosahedron. from Euler's formula I derived that number of faces is $20$.

I need to show that each face has a degree of $3$.

I that if each face has the same degree then we can conclude that the degree is $3$.

But I am not able to show that each face has the same degree.

Comment: I don't think it's true that every polyhedral graph with $12$ vertices and $30$ edges is the icosahedron. There is such a graph where the vertices don't all have the same degree.

Comment: @GerryMyerson are you sure? My argument below shows that the faces are triangles, making the answer a deltahedron. However the only (convex) deltahedron with 20 faces is an icosahedron. (I am not sure about the non-convex case.)

Comment: Actually the triangular bifrustum is an example with some coplanar faces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltahedron

Comment: I guess if one is interested in convex solids only, then the vertex degrees are are all smaller than 5, but the average vertex degree is 5, implying that they all must actually be 5.

Comment: @Cheer, suppose you have two pyramids, each with a ten-sided base, and you stick the bases together. Convex, $12$ vertices, $30$ edges, all faces triangles, lots of vertices of degree four, two vertices of degree ten. Not generally thought of as an icosahedron.

Comment: @GerryMyerson gotcha! I was implicitly assuming equilateral faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $2E=3f_3+4f_4+\cdots$ where $f_k$ is the number of faces of degree $k$. This gives us $60=3f_3+4f_4+\cdots$ where $f_3+f_4+\cdots =20$. Now suppose some $f_k\neq 0, k\geq 4$. Then $3f_3+4f_4+\cdots>3(f_3+f_4+\cdots)= 3\cdot 20 =60$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Where does that result come from / what is it called?

Comment: @Jollywatt if you count up the edges for each face you get $\sum kf_k$, but then each edge gets counted twice because it appears in exactly two faces.

Comment: Ha! Wonderfully simple. Thanks @Cheerful Parsnip.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip why $3f_3+4f_4+\cdots<3(f_3+f_4+\cdots)$, It should be $3f_3+4f_4+\cdots > 3(f_3+f_4+\cdots)$

Comment: @User8976 thanks for spotting the typo. Fixed.